# Minifigures - Series 20 The Knight

Tags: minifigures

Is the knight in the new Minifigures Series 20 based on the character in the movie *Monty Python and The Holy Grail*?

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Lego Knight]

Answer (score 4):

This seems to match my recollection of the major knights from the film, so pretty much probably not:
[image: Old deviantart image found on Pintrest "shields_from_some_knight_from_the_holy_grail_by_ejpokst"]

There wasn't a black (sable) and yellow (or) quartered knight, nor a martlet or raven on his shield.

That helmet element ([Mini Knight's Helmet Closed](https://brickset.com/parts/design-89520)) has been around since 2010, and has often been used in tournament and jousting sets, as well as general Castle sets of the time.